# Viewing Videos Retrieved from a Json File into a <Div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have the following code that displays videos from a json file into a list view, i want to be able to view the videos after i click on a list item after the videos are loaded from the json file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getVideos();
});

function getVideos() {
    var newsfeed = '';

    console.log("get vids");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'video.json',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data){
        console.log("response = " + JSON.stringify(data));
        data.forEach(function (item) {
          var title = item.Title; 
          var image = item.Image;
          var date = item.Date;
            var id = item.id;

          newsfeed = '<li><a href="#detailinfo" id="VideoFeeds"data-key="'+ item.id + '">';
            newsfeed += '<img height="80" width="85" src="' + item.Image + '" />';
            newsfeed += '<h3>' + item.Title + '</h3>';
            newsfeed += '<p>' + item.Date + '</p>';
            newsfeed += '</a></li>';
            $('#listoffeeds').append(newsfeed);
        });

        console.log("string - " + JSON.stringify(newsfeed));

        $('#listoffeeds').listview('refresh');

    }).fail(function(error){
        console.log("error - " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

        /*error: function(error){
            $('#status').text('Failed to get a feed...');
            console.log("error - " + error.toString());
        }*/


}'
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? You haven't asked a question.

Comment: i want the videos to be populated in a list and i click on a list item to view the videos on the same page.